# Creating a double sided plane using Three.dart. Nothing is shown on the browser when run

Tags: dart, webgl, dart-editor

Total newbie here. When I run this from the Dart editor, the browser opens, loads for a while and then shows an empty page. What is it that I'm doing wrong? How do I create a geometric plane using three.dart?

Here's the .dart file. Sorry about the poor formatting.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math' as Math;
import 'package:three/three.dart';
//import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';

Element container;
PerspectiveCamera camera;
Scene scene;
WebGLRenderer renderer;

void main() {
    init();
    animate(0);
}

void init() {
     container = new Element.tag('canvas');
     document.body.nodes.add(container);

     camera = new PerspectiveCamera(45.0, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1.0, 2000.00);
     camera.position.y = 400.0;

     scene = new Scene();
     scene.add(new AmbientLight(0x404040));
     var light = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
     light.position.setValues(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
     scene.add(light);

     var geometry = new PlaneGeometry(5, 20);
     var material = new MeshBasicMaterial(color: 0xffff00, side: DoubleSide);
     var plane = new Mesh(geometry, material);
     scene.add(plane);

     renderer = new WebGLRenderer();
     renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

onWindowResize(event) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

animate(num time) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

render() {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple errors(to be frank - it's totally messed up). [You can get working example here.](https://github.com/threeDart/three.dart/tree/master/example)  Also check browser's console log. If you have  `The built-in library 'dart:json' is not available on Dartium.` then you have old three.dart version. Make sure that your pubspec.yaml has proper dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
  vector_math: any
  three: ">=0.2.5+1 <0.3.0"
```